# Serving apple-app-site-association file on Vuejs

Tags: ios, vue.js, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am trying to enable Deep Linking in my mobile application. This means if someone tries to open a URL for my website on their phone, it will automatically open in the app instead. To do this, I need to make an apple-app-site-association file available via HTTPS on my website:

> After you create the apple-app-site-association file, upload it to the root of your HTTPS web server or to the `.well-known` subdirectory. The file needs to be accessible via HTTPS—without any redirects—at `https://<domain>/apple-app-site-association` or `https://<domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`.

How can I get VueJs to serve this static file when the URL is hit?

Comment: Did you google Universal Links? Check this out https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/

Comment: VueJS wouldn't serve that file...your need to use your website's web server to serve it.